# Why the actorSystem is not creating the actor to run with custom dispatcher

Tags: akka, akka-typed, akka-dispatcher

Hi have below typesafe config in file `application-typed.conf`.

```
    akka {
      loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
      loglevel = "DEBUG"
      logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
      actor {
        provider = "local"
      }
    }
    
    custom-thread-pool {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size = 40
      }
      throughput = 2
    }
```

Below is the akka-typed  actor code.

```
    import akka.actor.typed.{ActorSystem, Behavior, DispatcherSelector, PostStop, Signal}
    import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AbstractBehavior
    import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext
    import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
    import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
    
    trait PrintMessage
    case class PrintMessageAny(x: Any) extends PrintMessage
    
    object PrintMeActor {
      def apply(): Behavior[PrintMessage] =
        Behaviors.setup[PrintMessage](context => new PrintMeActor(context))
    }
    
    class PrintMeActor(context: ActorContext[PrintMessage]) extends AbstractBehavior[PrintMessage](context) {
      val dispatcherSelector: DispatcherSelector = DispatcherSelector.fromConfig("custom-thread-pool")
      implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = context.system.dispatchers.lookup(dispatcherSelector)
    
      println(s"PrintMeActor Application started in Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
    
      override def onMessage(msg: PrintMessage): Behavior[PrintMessage] = {
        // No need to handle any messages
        println(s"Got $msg in Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
        Behaviors.same
      }
    
      override def onSignal: PartialFunction[Signal, Behavior[PrintMessage]] = {
        case PostStop =>
          context.log.info("PrintMeActor Application stopped")
          this
      }
    }
    
    object TestTypedActorApp extends App {
      val config = ConfigFactory.load("application-typed.conf")
      val as: ActorSystem[PrintMessage] = ActorSystem(PrintMeActor(), "PrintAnyTypeMessage", config)
      as.tell(PrintMessageAny("test"))
      Thread.sleep(2000)
    }
```

When I run the code, I get the below output.

> PrintMeActor Application started in Thread PrintAnyTypeMessage-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6
> Got PrintMessageAny(test) in Thread PrintAnyTypeMessage-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6

I want this actor to run on the custom-thread-pool but it is not happening. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You associate the dispatcher with the actor when you spawn it, by passing an `akka.actor.typed.DispatcherSelector` (which extends `akka.actor.typed.Props`) corresponding to the desired dispatcher.

When spawning the `ActorSystem` on a custom dispatcher, one can only pass `Props` through the overloads that take either a `Config` or an `ActorSystemSetup`.

If wanting to override the actor for the user guardian actor (the actor with the behavior you passed into the `ActorSystem`), it may make more sense to make that dispatcher the default dispatcher:

```
 akka.actor.default-dispatcher {
   executor = "thread-pool-executor"

   thread-pool-executor {
     fixed-pool-size = 40
   }
   throughput = 2
 }
```